# Is it possible to have my Excel table linked into PowerPoint update automatically in PPT when a change occurs in the Excel source?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I copy a table in Excel > Paste Special > Paste Link > Hit OK and my table shows in my PPT slide

If I right click on my table, I can click update link, which will update the slide to reflect any changes in the spreadsheet

Problem is, the Excel table changes automatically, several times every hour, I can't be hitting the update link every time, any way to make the slide update automatically either if changes occur in the Excel table or every 2-3 minutes would work too? Using Excel and PPT 2013 by the way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way:

```
ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
```

will update all the links in your presentation.

Of course, if you have a specific presentation in mind, you can use that one instead of ActivePresentation.

However, I don't know any way to update links one-by-one without side effects. You could use

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).OLEFormat.DoVerb wdOLEVerbPrimary
```

but this will open Excel Applications or Workbooks and there is no good way of Closing them and Hiding them while they are being used.